# 301 ResponseCode in RestTemplate Client

Tags: spring, rest

I am trying to consume a service using RestTemplate in Spring. I tried around and each time getting 301 as response code. However, I am good to get a json response from the same uri while using POSTMAN.

Here is the code to get the statelist:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
String baseUri = "http://www.whizapi.com/api/v2/util/ui/in/indian-states-list";
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(baseUri)
                .queryParam("project-app-key","my-key");
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);
ResponseEntity<String> stats = restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().toUri(),
                HttpMethod.GET,entity ,String.class);
```

Please suggest if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 301 is a permanent redirect. You are accessing an outmoded url.

Having checked this url `http://www.whizapi.com/api/v2/util/ui/in/indian-states-list` redirected to `https://www.whizapi.com/api/v2/util/ui/in/indian-states-list.ashx`.

The same can be seen in Location response header as shown in the below image.

[image: Location Response Header]

So, you should directly request `https://www.whizapi.com/api/v2/util/ui/in/indian-states-list.ashx` from your restTemplate object.

More details could be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)

Hope this helps!